# Lowering iOS deployment target

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, ios10

I have an app that currently has "iOS Deployment Target: 9.0".

I am going to release a new version and I want to *temporarily* change that to "iOS Deployment Target: 10.0" until I am able to test the new release more thoroughly on `iOS 9`.

Will Apple allow me to lower the target back to 9.0 in a future release? Or am I stuck with 10.0 if I make that change in the next release.

I have not found any documentation regarding this scenario, so I assume it would not be a problem, but I have also seen iTunes Connect reject binaries for other undocumented reasons.

Any advice?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such policy, but consider the fact that your 9.0 users may uninstall your app the second they discover that you dropped support for 9.0.

Comment: "but I have also seen iTunes Connect reject binaries for other undocumented reasons" So you grant that Apple's behavior is unpredictable and then you ask us to predict Apple's behavior.

Comment: That may not be a problem. [Reference from Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6125198?tstart=0)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092866/can-i-raise-my-ios-apps-deployment-target-to-a-more-recent-os-now-and-later-o

Comment: Related issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37159152/3687801)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change iOS Deployment Target `9.0` to `10.0` and in future again lower it to 9.0. Apple does not have problem with OS version support.

*Just make sure, Base SDK supportable to 9.0. (All libraries, frameworks and classes should be available in lowered version)*

You can use features from system versions later than the deployment target—up to and including the OS version you've selected as your base SDK—but you must check for the availability of all features in both versions.